# NetSuite Saved Search Language

Tags: sql, formula, netsuite

Okay.  I am trying to make a statement in NetSuite where the following is needed:

I pay a bill in March that is posted in April (Imagine the bill is for rent in April but I pay it in March).

My A/P Aging is not tying to the balance sheet.

The problem is that NetSuite sorts the months by Alphabetically so when i tell the saved search to show what was made in March and Posted in april, it wont let me, because it is expressed as Posting Period = April and Bill Payment = Less Than April  it fails.  As april alphabetically is number 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two different criteria and no formula. You can do Posting Period is April as one and do Bill Payment (date) is before April 1, 2016.